# Two-dimensional array for decoding binary-decimal

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, decimal

Well simply put l need  to create  2d array using 0 and 1 then  each row  decode from binary form to decimal (array is a[5][8]). My idea is to use pointer for each row (would have 5 void function but l had problem with first so l stopped). All l get is some random number instead of simple array. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake ?  Here is  my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void VredBajt(int a[5][8],int *pb)
{
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        pb=&(a[0][j]);
        pb++;
    }}}

int main()
{
   int a[5][8],i,j,pb;
   srand(time(0));
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=rand()%(2);
    }
   }
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        printf("%3d",a[i][j]); 
    }
   }

    VredBajt(a,&pb);
    printf("\n\n %5d",pb);
}
```

Comment: What's the output? What do you expect the output to be? Have you identified what might be going wrong?

Comment: @sftrabbit well pb should in current program should be first line of 2d array (2d array is generated by function random so pb should be  random number consisted of 8 zeros and ones) but it outputs something like 4534036...

Comment: @sftrabbit yes but it should be written  first line's binary form is_________ and its  decimal value is _________.  my second nested  loop prints   array

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
pb=&(a[0][j]);
```

To:

```
*pb=a[0][j];
```

Although, it is still unclear what you are hoping to achieve by assigning different values to variable `pb` in the `for` loop in function `VredBajt` (this variable will only retain the last value assigned to it).

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
void VredBajt(int a[4][8],int *pb)
{
    int val = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            val <<= 1;
            val |= a[i][j];
        }
    }
    *pb = val;
}
```

It is still unclear whether you want function `VredBajt` to return a single value for the entire table, or a single value for each row in the table.

The above implementation assumes that you want a single value for the entire table.

Hence, I had to change from 5 to 4, since `int` can only store up to 32 bits (4 * 8).

Comment: @barak manos  that changes nothing...it simply outputs  different numbers like 7684019...

Comment: @user3127589: It is still unclear what you are hoping to achieve by assigning different values to variable `pb` in the `for` loop in function `VredBajt` (this variable will only retain the last value assigned to it).

Comment: @barak manos  2d array is made of 0 and 1...each line has 8 of them and pb should be pointer to the first line...since  each line is 0 and 1 its binary number and l should decode it to decimal number...but instead of binary number  pb shows wrong random number

Comment: You are not being clear about the expected output. Is it the decimal value of 40 bits? If yes, then why are you using a 2-dimensional array (instead of a 1-dimensional array)?

Comment: @barak manos  it the text of program that l should write it was specified  that l must use 2d array as a  base and start from there...final output should be  number like 171 (binary combination would be 10101011) pb should be 10101011 but  in my case is 7680569...

Comment: @barakmanos: I guess each 8-bit converted number should be stored in a new 1d array or be printed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the VredBajt function, you manipulate the passed pb pointer, but this has no effect once the function is finished.
In main, pb is an integer which was never initialised and never assigned, so printing it shows a random number.

If you must convert an array of ints containing 0 or 1, then you can shift that in a new integer and print that.

```
int dec = 0;
for (int i = 7; i != 0; --i) 
{ 
  dec <<= 1; 
  dec += a[0][i]; 
}
```

Comment: thx that realy solved my problem  but l have one more problem...it now shows  decimal value and l should print both binary and decimal...thats what l try to do and l my main problem is  how to print binary value since it is given in 2d array

Comment: @user3127589: you are printing the binary value: see your second nested loop.